# Wordpress 3.5 pagination for posts

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm having trouble to get pagination work in page which shows specific category posts.
Pagination shows up, but it doesn't change pages. Some help would be great, thanks!

This is my code in index.php file:

```
<?php
if (is_page('Blog') || is_category('Blogposts')) { 
$post_per_page = '3'; 
$args=array('category_name' => 'Blogposts', 'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page);
?>

<?php 
query_posts($args); 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php          the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <p><?php the_time('j.n.Y')?></<p>
            <p><?php comments_number('No comments','1 comment','% comments'); ?></p>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

  <?php endwhile; 
      endif; 

  wp_pagenavi();

 next_posts_link('« Previous Post' );
 previous_posts_link('Next Post »' );

 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use some thing like

```
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array('category_name' => 'Blogposts', 'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page, 'paged' => $page);
```

in your first code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $category=get_category_by_slug('home');

   $category_id = $category->term_id;

   $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
         query_posts( "cat=5&showposts=2&paged=".$paged);
   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

   ?>

 <div class="contentTitle"> <?php the_title(); ?> </div>
 <div class="contentText"><?php the_content();?> </div>

   <?php  endwhile; endif; ?>
   <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) : ?>
                           <div class=`enter code here`"pnavi">
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
                           </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <div class="alignleft"><?php// next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries')); ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php// previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;')); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please explain your code. ("_why does it solve the question?_")